# Why should i avoid custom service applications on windows to run as local service user?

Tags: windows-10, windows-services

I've read an article about developing self hosted web applications hosted as windows service - within the article it mentions that i should avoid using the local service account for such applications.

**Why is that?**

I've got quite some issues setting up a connection to the local database partially because of this, so perhaps understanding that bit helps me figure out my connection errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"One advantage of running under the LocalSystem account is that the service has complete unrestricted access to local resources. This is also the disadvantage of LocalSystem because a LocalSystem service can do things that would bring down the entire system. In particular, a service running as LocalSystem on a domain controller (DC) has unrestricted access to Active Directory Domain Services. This means that bugs in the service, or security attacks on the service, can damage the system or, if the service is on a DC, damage the entire enterprise network."

Short answer is, it is a Big security risk.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/the-localsystem-account)

Comment: I assume that a freshly created user which is used for just services has none of these vulnerabilities and only access to the folders i give it access to? Because that would indeed explain this suggestion. I wasn't aware how powerful LocalService is...